# Git rebase after merge confused about deleted file

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

My Git repository has two files, `alpha` and `beta`, with identical content.

If I delete `alpha` in my master branch, and edit it in my feature branch, then when I merge master into feature, I'm warned about a conflict. Assume I resolve this by deleting `alpha`.

If I then rebase my feature branch onto master using `git rebase master`, `alpha` is deleted, but the changes I made to `alpha` on the feature branch are now applied to `beta`! I get a conflict warning but it's happily resolved with an auto-merge without the commit being blocked for me to review.

Interestingly, if I do a `git rebase -i` and just accept the default, `beta` isn't edited and I get to resolve the same conflict I resolved at merge time.

Three related questions then:

1. Why does Git think the change I applied to one file should be applied to another, when the other hasn't been edited by any commit?
2. How can I avoid this sort of situation?
3. Why is the behaviour different for an interactive rebase, even when I take the default options?

I'm running Git 1.7.9 on Cygwin on Win7. I've put a [transcript on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Lfb9jRy0) showing this starting with a `git init` in an empty directory, if anyone wants to see the details for themselves (I'm not posting it here due to length).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [documentation for `git-rebase`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase):

> -m
>   --merge
>   Use merging strategies to rebase. When the recursive (default) merge strategy is used, this allows rebase to be aware of renames on the upstream side.

When a file is deleted, Git considers that a candidate for a rename, and tries to apply the rebased patch to the corresponding renamed file. It sounds like it might have made a poor guess in your case.

You can use the `-m` option to select a different merge strategy. For example, the `resolve` merge strategy may avoid this problem with auto-detecting renames (see [`git-merge`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) for details on merge strategies).

Comment: another possible solution would be to play with the `rename-threshold` option of the `recursive` strategy. Setting it to `M100%`, should solve the issue with the bad guess.